# animate rectangle into parallelogram

Tags: android, animation, transformation

I am trying to animate a transition from rectangle to a parallelogram
In general it should look something like:

```
---------------                 --------------
|             |                /             /
|             |               /             /
|             |      ==>     /             /
|             |             /             /
---------------             --------------
```

I am trying to dust off my linear algebra skills, and if I am not mistaken, I will need a transform matrix which will look somthing like

```
(1,             r)
(0   ,sqrt(1-r^2))
```

where r is between 0 and 1 and should represent the rate of the transformation.

My question is, how do I animate a view using that matrix?

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan we decided to go on a different animation, so never got to get to the bottom of this. Sorry.

Comment: if you want to create this shape you can create it